# Exception in UWP on device and emulator

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll, uwp

So, the problem: I have working application on UWP, written on C# and C++. It works as it must work on desktop in releas and debug modes. It worked on mobile devices and emulator not so long before some changes happend in C++ part. But now application crashes at the begining of C++ part if application opens on emulator or mobile. MSVS gives me this messages, but It does't helped:

- Exception thrown at 0x7767B928 (ntdll.dll) in rhodes.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
- Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.Interop.dll
- The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
- Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Private.Interop.dll
- Exception thrown at 0x76EA2812 (KernelBase.dll) in rhodes.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x8007007F, 0x00000050, 0x03B0E2DC).

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to install application using Publish option.  ntdll.dll is a dll that the is used by the Net Library and required on PCs where application is running.  Either it is missing on installed PC or the wrong version of dll is on the installed PC.  When you public and application and install the needed dlls are also installed.  The issue is probably occurring because the Net Library isn't installed on  PCs.  So publish application and then running the setup.exe like any commercial software package will install the missing dlls

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense. ntdll.dll is core part of the Windows operating system - it is not deployed with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception, and enable breaking on all exception types (C++, CLR and Win32) ones. Depending on where the issue comes from, you'll need to use either native or managed mode debugging (you can set it in Project Properties -> Debug tab). Now, the project should hit a breakpoint when you hit that exception, which will point you to where it is coming from.

Comment: In that case I'm getting a message: Exception thrown at 0x76EA2812 in app.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Cn::XH at memory location 0x0387E634

Comment: Just continue past the exceptions you don't care about.

Comment: Yeah, but it will stop at that exception and you'll be able to inspect it.